# WebClient Wikipedia illegal path characters even after url encode

Tags: c#, webclient, screen-scraping, wikipedia

I am trying to do a simple screen scrape from Wikipedia using the HTML Agility pack. I copied the format of a proper link that works in my browser, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanticoke%2c_Pennsylvania <- Works in browser
However when using this code I get the illegal path characters exception from the WebClient class.

Original Address: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanticoke,_Pennsylvania

Update - downloading the website to a string variable before calling html.Load() doesn't throw the exception. I get illegal path characters on html.Load()

Exception Data: [image]

```
var client = new WebClient();
var address = $"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{HttpUtility.UrlEncode($"{name},_{state}")}";

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
html.Load(client.DownloadString(address)); //Exception thrown here
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a) the actual URL that's generated and b) the actual exception you get?

Comment: You have not posted the actual URL AFTER encoding. Also, move your `client.DownloadString` out of `html.Load` and assign it to a string variable so we can actually determine if it's an issue with the URL, or the response from Wikipedia thus throwing an exception in HAP

Comment: Load takes a url not raw html. Use LoadHtml to load html from a string.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong method. Load will attempt to pull the website down, LoadHtml excepts the already loaded content.

```
html.LoadHtml(content);
```